# Google Cloud Platform: Any way to rearrange fields in an existing Data Catalog template?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-data-catalog

I've added a new field to an existing GCP Data Catalog template which by default adds it to the bottom. I'd like for this new field to appear higher up.  Is there some way I'm not seeing to rearrange the order of fields in a DC template?  If that isn't possible and I'll be forced to recreate the template, is there a way to export the DC metadata and then import it into a new version of the template?  Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: You are right, I cannot see an option to change the order of the fields. I went ahead and created a [Feature Request to allow us to reorder the fields](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/177658648) in a tag template. You can click the Vote for this issue and get email notifications icon (the star) to register your support for the feature. In the meantime, I’m afraid the workaround is recreating the tag with the desired order or try the REST method posted in the answer given by mesmacosta.

Comment: Thank you for logging this as a feature request rsantiago.  I starred it. The suggestion from @mesmacosta worked for me and I can use this for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This answer uses the Data Catalog **REST API** as example.** If you use the client library or gcloud SDK check the proper documentation.

Have you tried to use the `order` attribute on the TagTemplateField resource?

In the PATCH Tag Template Field API call:
[PATCH https://datacatalog.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project}/locations/{location}/tagTemplates/{tagtemplate}/fields/{field}](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.tagTemplates.fields/patch)

You can update the [TagTemplateField](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.tagTemplates.fields#TagTemplateField) order:

```
{
  "name": string,
  "displayName": string,
  "type": {
    object (FieldType)
  },
  "isRequired": boolean,
  "description": string,
  "order": integer
}
```

Regarding exporting DC metadata, there is an open source package [datacatalog-util](https://github.com/mesmacosta/datacatalog-util) that you can use to **export** your tag-templates and tags, and then **import** them using the same package.

Comment: Thank you mesmacosta - I should have thought to look into the API as a workaround for now.  It worked fine.  I'll also look into your repo -- interesting!